# Get the correct height of Usercontrol for VSTO when Menu Ribbon is pinned?

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I am developing a Outlook 2013 Addin. I have a Panel which I align to bottom of the user control programatically by:

```
botpanel.Location=New Point(0,Me.height-botpanel.Height-5)
```

This works fine when the Menu Ribbon is not pinned.But When the Ribbon is pinned the botpanel goes beyond the visible screen.

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually caused by the panel above it.
I re-initiated the above panel as

```
abv_panel.location=New Point(0,0)
```

So that re-initiating this location of panel on User-Control Resize event will bring back everything normal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the panel location programatically, set the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the Panel to [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at design time. This way the panel will be automatically positioned when the UserControl is resized (due to the Ribbon being pinned \ unpinned).